# Query result to a collection of object

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database phpmyadmin, I created a class :

```
<?php

class Ticket
{
private $NumDossier = 0;
private $NomTicket ="";
private $Service = "" ;
private $Impact = 0;
private $Urgence = "";
private $DateOuverture = "";

public function __construct($p_NumDossier, $p_NomTicket,$p_Service,$p_Impact,$p_Urgence,$p_DateOuverture)
{
    $this->NumDossier = $p_NumDossier;
    $this->NomTicket = $p_NomTicket;
    $this->Service = $p_Service;
    $this->Impact = $p_Impact;
    $this->Urgence = $p_Urgence;
    $this->DateOuverture = $p_DateOuverture;
}
public function getNumDossier()
{
    return $this->NumDossier;
}
public function getNomTicket()
{
    return $this->NomTicket;
}
public function getService()
{
    return $this->Service;
}
public function getImpact()
{
    return $this->Impact;
}public function getUrgence()
{
    return $this->Urgence;
}
public function getDateOuverture()
{
    return $this->DateOuverture;
}
} 
?>
```

For all row that my query return I want to create an object and add it to a collection.

My code :

```
$connexion = cnx(); 

if($connexion) { 
    $requete="SELECT * FROM ticket '"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($connexion, $requete); 
    $result = mysqli_query($connexion, $requete); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
 } 

$test = new Ticket(0,"","",0,"",""); 

while($row) { 
    //create object for each line and add it to an collection 
}
```

If you have a solution/lead me to this issue.

Thanks for read !

Comment: Where is your query? What should the collection be able to do? Just hold the tickets, or more?

Comment: The DB have : NumDossier, NomTicket,Service,Impact,Urgence,DateOuverture and the query was SELECT * FROM ticket (ticket was the name of my table)

Comment: I meant; "Where is the query in your PHP code?". You have chosen an interface to your database and I can't guess which one.

Comment: thank Mickaël Leger for edit the post :)

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to assume that the beginning part of your code is correct, so I copied that. But I changed it further on. You want to retrieve multiple rows, so I put the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` inside the while loop. With each new row I create a new ticket and put it in a 'collection' array.

```
$connection = cnx(); 

if ($connexion) { 
    $query ="SELECT * FROM ticket"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 
    if ($result === false) die("The query [$query] could not be executed.");

    $collection = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $collection[] = new Ticket($row["NumDossier"],
                                   $row["NomTicket"],
                                   $row["Service"],
                                   $row["Impact"],
                                   $row["Urgence"],
                                   $row["DateOuverture"]); 
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($collection);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

So I used a simple array for the collection. I used the default numeric array indexing because I wouldn't know what to replace it with. `$row["NomTicket"]` seems a logical choice.